# preinstall script how to set npm config to current directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to set the current directory that the user is installing from to an npm config variable so that I can reference this in my install script.

Is there any way I can do it via command line or am I going to have to write a script to do this?

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm config set base_path CURRENT_PATH_HERE?"
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the env you are using to run your npm install command.
if you use a bash shell then you can use

> "preinstall": "npm config set base_path $(pwd)"

while in a DOS shell you would use:

> "preinstall": "npm config set base_path %cd%"

package scripts are simply "passed" to the shell and then executed, so you have to figure out how you can get the path as a variable.